# Making a graph plot - Need to calculate x and y in own thread

Tags: android

So, I am making a graph. Calculating x and y is beeing done width a for-loop that goes from 0 to 5000. It takes to long time to load, so I was thinking of putting in it own thread and maby plot as the numbers are calculated, rather than plot when everything is finished?

I have to files, Graph.java takes in a equation and sends it to GraphDrawer.java for plotting.

Graph: http://pastebin.com/tBvr1d03
GraphDrawer: http://pastebin.com/8ZwUS75u

Comment: no tags in subject please http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles and add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on `AsyncTask`, it does what you want.

Run your calculations in `doInBackground()`, make calls to `publishProgress()` to send your updates to the UI thread, and implement `onProgressUpdate()` to receive those updates and graph them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, performing slow operations in their own thread is generally advisable. The main thread being blocked for extended periods (many seconds) is both bad for user experience and may result in Android deciding that the process has run into trouble, and offering a Forced Close.

However, you can/should definitely not continuously update the UI with a graph generated in a non-UI thread, as manipulating the UI from multiple threads can give undefined results. [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more information, particularly under "worker threads".